# JQuery.makeArray() getting values from HTMLOListElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I'm trying to get values from my HTMLOListElement object, but allways return undefined.

This is my function:

```
$("#finish").click(function(){
    var elems = document.getElementById( "selectable2" );
    var arr = jQuery.makeArray( elems );
    arr.reverse();              
    confirm("It will generate the group: " +groupname+ " with that users:" +arr+"."); 
});
```

*selectable2* - this is a list on Jquery.

Finally allways get the same from the Confirm windows:

**It will generate the group: examplegroup with that users:[object HTMLOListElement].**

How can i get the values tag from that object?

Thanks everyone.
Marc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list of li's you have to specify that in selector passed to `$.makearray()` so you could use `querySelectorAll` as `document.querySelectorAll("#selectable2 li")`, check the example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#finish").click(function(){
  var groupname = "examplegroup";
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#selectable2 li");
  var arr = jQuery.makeArray( elems );
  arr.reverse();        
  
  console.log(arr);

  console.log("It will generate the group: " +groupname+ " with that users:" +arr+".");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="selectable2">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
<button id="finish">Finish</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Zakaria!!! It works, but finally I simplified to this:

var users =[];
     
$("#selectable2 li").each(function() {
    users.push($(this).text());
});